# NetworkStatsManager's queries take too long

Tags: android, networkstatsmanager

I'm trying to get statistics of traffic used on last 30days on each application using `NetworkStatsManager` , so i wrote a code as following :

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {

NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager = (NetworkStatsManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NETWORK_STATS_SERVICE);
    NetworkStats networkStats = null;
    Log.d("CCC","start----"+System.currentTimeMillis());
    networkStats = networkStatsManager.querySummary(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI,"",
                                System.currentTimeMillis()-2592000000L,
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
    Log.d("CCC","END-"+System.currentTimeMillis());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {}

    NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = new NetworkStats.Bucket();
    while (networkStats!=null && networkStats.hasNextBucket()) {
    networkStats.getNextBucket(bucket);  
    Log.d("CCC",bucket.getUid()+"---"+bucket.getTxBytes()+"---"+bucket.getRxBytes());
}
});
thread.start();
```

Returned result seems to be correct but **the problem** is, query takes too much time to respond -**usually 25 seconds**- and if i want to get both `TYPE_WIFI` and `TYPE_MOBILE` internet usage it will be **over 50 seconds**, which is not something good.
So is there another approach to do this? Or perhaps i am doing something wrong here that causes this delay?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Apparently this only happends when you use NetworkStatsManager inside a thread . if you run the code on UIThread it would respond in about -500ms- which is very good but still makes the ui non-smooth.